# How to retrieve TextBox Value from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I have a `gridview` and created dynamic `TextBox` in the `RowDataBound` event as

```
TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
txtbox.ID = "txt1";
txtControl.Text = "SoomeValue";
```

When I'm trying to retrieve the value on a `button click` as

```
    TextBox textboxValue = (TextBox)gv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].FindControl("txt1");
    string value = textboxValue.Text;
```

It is always returning `null` beside it is having the `value`

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5942081/3922214

Answer (score 1):

Answer is No. You cannot retrieve dynamically added TextBox from GridView like you are trying.

If you use GridView, you need to add textbox inside Template Column at **Design Time**.

Comment: I would like to do it dynamically @Win

Comment: Ideally, you place textbox inside GridView at design time, then you manipulate show/hide inside [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx). If you really want to add controls dynamically, you need to do it manually by yourself without GridView - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16346427/296861) which is a lot more work than GridView.

Comment: isn't it possible to avoid re-creating them on every `postback` and still retain its value and I just mentioned `TextBox` control but it can be any `Control`

Comment: Answer is no. You need to reload dynamically added controls in post back; it is by design of ASP.Net WebForm. If you do not like it, you might want to consider using ASP.Net MVC.